# Pandas df.plot set color proportional to a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colormap

#### Question:

I have a `pandas` dataframe `df` with 6 rows representing different variables.
I want to plot the two first columns in a bar graph and I would like to use the third column `score` to colorize the bars based on an existing colormap, for example the `matplotlib` viridis one.

This dataframe looks like this:

```
    ID  count   score
0    4      1       3
1    5      4       4
2    5      8       5
3    3      7       2
4    1      5       5
5    1      3       4
```

What my code looks like for the moment:

```
df.plot('ID', 'count', kind='bar', figsize=(15,5), ax=plt.subplot(122), colors=cm.viridis.colors)
plt.show()
```

But the color of all bar is a unique purple.
I want, let say, to sample the viridis colormap proportionally to values in my `score` column.
Is there a simple way to achieve that?

#### Edit [2019-10-31]:

Using `seaborn` as proposed in the first answer gives me an error:

```
my_palette = sns.color_palette(plt.get_cmap('viridis'), 5)
sns.barplot(x="New ID", y="count", hue="Note", data=df, palette=my_palette)
```

The error returned:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-1943cafa0d79> in <module>
----> 1 my_palette = sns.color_palette(plt.get_cmap('viridis'), 5)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/seaborn/palettes.py in color_palette(palette, n_colors, desat)
    238 
    239     # Always return as many colors as we asked for
--> 240     pal_cycle = cycle(palette)
    241     palette = [next(pal_cycle) for _ in range(n_colors)]
    242 

TypeError: 'ListedColormap' object is not iterable
```

#### Edit [2019-11-05]:

Using the proposed code lead the resulting graph to have misaligned bars with the x-ticks (which I expected to be centered under the bar on the x-axis), especially when there is only one bar per category as the next figure shows:

[image: misaligned bars and x-ticks]

In addition, I would like to be able to take into consideration `'NaN'` values in the `df['count']` column. 
Currently, if there is one `'NaN'` value, it raises a:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`
So, I have to set this value equal to 0 even if it is NOT truly a zero.

Comment: What colour would you want if there's a NaN in 'score'?

Comment: But if there is 'NaN' in my `count` attribute, there is actually no bar. So, the color doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is to use [seaborn.barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) this way:

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.barplot(x="ID", y="count", hue="score", data=df, palette=your_palette)
```

You can create a palette this way:

```
your_palette = sns.color_palette('inferno', n_point)
```

where `n_point` are the number of different colors in your custome palette.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this gave me an error. My version of `seaborn` is 0.9.0 (downloaded from PyPi using `pip`).

Comment: I changed the code. Sorry for the error. color_palette is a method that accepts the name of a colormap and the number of point. I tested it again and it works now.

Comment: I can see that the bars are randomly aligned with the x-ticks, this is annoying and I've search the documentation without finding anything to fix it.

Comment: I don't think they are 'randomly' aligned. The sample data you provided has two entries with id=1. How would you like these to be plotted?